# Dropbox on Samsung Galaxy - where is the Settings button?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, dropbox

On a Sony Xperia, the settings button in Dropbox is top right.
On a Samsung Galaxy, there is no settings button top right and I have been unable to find it anywhere else. Where is it?

・On a HTC device, the settings button is right up there as well.

Comment: What is version of your Android OS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your phone has a *menu* hard key, like most Samsung phones, the three-dots icon for an *overflow menu* won't appear. Press the menu key instead, and **Settings** is the bottom item on the menu.

Comment: Right. There was a menu key that was invisible until I pushed it. Hmm...